# loadScript in LWC throwing error - because of location object

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom, js

I am using a third party library which is using global location variable and it throw the error when run that js code using loadScript in lwc.

I wrote a few lines of below custom js code to run as static resource and I am printing the global variable to see the output.

Static resource file code

```
(function () {
  console.log('##Test: location output #::', location)
  console.log('##Test: window output #::', window)
  console.log('##Test: window.location output #::', window.location)
  })();
```

I also console the logs in lwc different lifecycle hooks.

```
renderedCallback() {
      console.log('location in lwc renderedCallback::', location);
       this.loadstaticresource();
}
```

on lwc "location" global variable print output correctly but inn static resource it's value is undefined

console output

[image: console image]

what to do so it doesn't print null for location variable, it prints value with window.global but in third party API I can't use that.